# switching from http to https(mtls) for minio i am receiving "message": "invalid Login"

Tags: minio, mtls

switching from http to https(mtls) for minio i am receiving "message": "invalid Login".
Before switching to mtls, i could successfully login with the given credentials:
MINIO_ROOT_USER="username"
MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD="password"

Moreover the certificate is not the issue, the browser accepts/recognises the certificate as a valid certificate. The certificate is issued for the DNS and not the host_IP, although the dns record is mapped for this host_IP, nslookup resolves correctly.

```
ls -l /etc/minio/ssl
-rw-r--r-- 1 minio minio 3272 Jan 12 15:02 private.key
-rw-r--r-- 1 minio minio 2419 Jan 12 15:03 public.crt
```

```
uname -a
Linux minio 6.1.0-15-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.66-1 (2023-12-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
minio --version
minio version RELEASE.2024-01-13T07-53-03Z (commit-id=993d96feef0e6b93d963932a66e2a50d3157575e)
Runtime: go1.21.5 linux/amd64
License: GNU AGPLv3 <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html>
Copyright: 2015-2024 MinIO, Inc.
```

```
less /etc/minio/minio.conf:

# Minio local/remote volumes.
MINIO_VOLUMES="/var/lib/minio"

# Minio cli options.
MINIO_OPTS="--address host_IP:9091 --console-address host_IP:9092 --certs-dir /etc/minio/ssl "

# Access Key of the server.
MINIO_ROOT_USER="username"
# Secret key of the server.
MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD="password"


# Minio server URL
MINIO_SERVER_URL="https://host_IP:9091"
```

```
systemctl status minio
● minio.service - MinIO
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/minio.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-01-15 14:23:47 CET; 7s ago
       Docs: https://docs.min.io
    Process: 84354 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c if [ -z "${MINIO_VOLUMES}" ]; then echo "Variable MINIO_VOLUMES not set in /etc/minio/minio.conf"; exit 1; fi (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 84356 (minio)
      Tasks: 10
     Memory: 98.1M
        CPU: 2.980s
     CGroup: /system.slice/minio.service
             └─84356 /usr/local/bin/minio server --address host_IP:9091 --console-address host_IP:9092 --certs-dir /etc/minio/ssl /var/lib/minio

Jan 15 14:23:47 rainbow systemd[1]: Started minio.service - MinIO.
Jan 15 14:23:49 rainbow minio[84356]: MinIO Object Storage Server
Jan 15 14:23:49 rainbow minio[84356]: Copyright: 2015-2024 MinIO, Inc.
Jan 15 14:23:49 rainbow minio[84356]: License: GNU AGPLv3 <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html>
Jan 15 14:23:49 rainbow minio[84356]: Version: RELEASE.2024-01-13T07-53-03Z (go1.21.5 linux/amd64)
Jan 15 14:23:49 rainbow minio[84356]: Status:         1 Online, 0 Offline.
Jan 15 14:23:49 rainbow minio[84356]: S3-API: https://host_IP:9091
Jan 15 14:23:49 rainbow minio[84356]: Console: https://host_IP:9092
Jan 15 14:23:49 rainbow minio[84356]: Documentation: https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/index.html
Jan 15 14:23:49 rainbow minio[84356]: Warning: The standard parity is set to 0. This can lead to data loss.
```

I tried to deploy using dns alias instead the host_IP, but then the instance is not reachable via browser.

Comment: You must specify the hostname that matches the certificate and not the IP address for connections. An exception is if the certificate SAN contains the IP address which is not common and sometimes difficult to purchase.